# Program for removing comments in C++ not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, fstream

I have created a program in c++ to remove the commments of a c/c++ file and put a comment-removed version in another file. However after hours of debugging it is still not working. Help please!

"input" is a string that has the folder location of the c/c++ files.
"files" is a vector with all the file names in the folder but not their locations.
I use "input" and "files" to get the file name and location.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < files.size();i++ ){//for loop start

iteratora++;
string filename1 = input;
filename1.append("\\");
filename1.append(files[iteratora + 2]);

    cout << "\n" << filename1 << ".\n";
    cout << "Iterator: " << iteratora << ".\n";

programFile.clear();
ifstream afile (filename1);//(filename1);
fstream temp ("temp/temp.txt",std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);

string line;//variable for holding the characters in one line

remove_comments(afile,temp);


if (temp.is_open())
{
    while ( getline (temp,line) )
    {
        //cout << line << '\n';
        if (line != ""){
            cout << line;
        programFile.push_back(line);
        line = "";
        }

    }
    temp.close();
}

temp.clear();



 if (showVerbose == true){
       print_vector(programFile);//used to know what is in the file
   }


}
```

remove comments function

```
void remove_comments ( ifstream& Source , fstream& Target)
{
string line;
bool flag = false;


while ( ! Source.eof() ) // This loop is to get assure that the whole input file is read.
{


getline(Source, line); // To read line by line.

if ( flag )
{   if ( line.find("*/") < line.length() )
flag = false;
line.erase(0,line.find("*/") + 2);
}


if ( line.find("/*") < line.length() ) // searching for " /* " to eliminat it and all its content.
flag = true;
if ( ! flag )
{
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++ )
{

if(i<line.length())
if ( ( line.at(i) == '/' ) && ( line.at(i + 1 ) == '/' ) ) // searching for " // " to eliminate all its content.
break;
else
Target << line[i]; // To copy lines in the output file.

}

Target<<endl;


}



}

Source.close(); // to close the opened files.
Target.close(); 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: a) A program to remove comments in C++ can´t be that easy => You´re doing it wrong. String literals, preprocessor commands, etc.etc. ...?

Comment: this is basic, just removing the "//" and "/*" style comments

Comment: Can you tell us why its not working, ie. specific issues?

Comment: @Naan Yes, I understood that. There are no other kinds of comments in the first place.

Comment: Just use regex, its about 10 lines whole program

Comment: @MatjažMav That´s even worse. Much worse.

Comment: so basically, when i run the program the file temp.txt is supposed to have a version of the inputed file but without comments, however it has nothing in it

Comment: You use `while (getline(...))` in one place and incorrectly use `while (!Source.eof())` in another (you never ensure the input was successful before using `line`, and `eof()` returning `false` does not imply that there's more data to be read).

Comment: soooo... what should i change

Comment: Please consistently indent the code.  Suggest 4 spaces after every '{' and un-indent before every '}'.   Do not use tabs for indentation was each editor/wordprocessor, etc has the tab stops/tab width set differently.   Suggesting 4 spaces because 1) several levels of indentation does not result in lines beyond the right end of the screen  2) 4 spaces is wide enough to show, even when using a variable width font.

Comment: When OP has a runtime problem, please post code that cleanly compiles, so we do not have to create some compilable file (and hope that it is the same as the OPs file)

Comment: uhh what is a OP? sorry im new at this

Comment: @Naan, Original Poster, A.K.A. you.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Comments in code is a good idea

Comment: Dare I say that this sounds like a job for a different language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution.
It opens `file.txt` and loads the entire file into a `string`. Then it removes the
comments and writes the new data in `string` back into `file.txt`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {

        string source;
        ifstream readFile("file.txt");
        getline(readFile, source, '\0');    
        readFile.close();

        cout<<"\n---b e f o r e -----------------------------------\n\n";
         cout << source;

        while(source.find("/*") != string::npos) {
            size_t Beg = source.find("/*");
            source.erase(Beg, (source.find("*/", Beg) - Beg)+2);
        }

        while(source.find("//") != string::npos) {
            size_t Beg = source.find("//");
            source.erase(Beg, source.find("\n", Beg) - Beg);
        }   

       ofstream writefile("file.txt");
       writefile <<source;
       writefile.close();



       cout<<"\n\n-- a f t e r -------------------------------------------\n\n";


        cout << source;
        cout<<"\n---------------------------------------------\n\n";
        cout<<"\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

find method of string returns std::string::npos on unsuccessful search , so you should write this line

```
if(line.find("/*") < line.length())
```

as below:

```
if(line.find("/*") != std::string::npos)
```

Make similar changes and try.

Comment: While you should use the second, the first will still work due to `npos` being -1, which is congruent to the maximum value of the unsigned `size_type`, meaning that it will be greater than or equal to the length.

Comment: the program worked when i read directly form the source file and printed its contents. When i try to remove the comments, put it in temp/temp.txt and then print the contents of temp/temp.txt, it shows as if nothing is there in that file.